# How to use Query function with Arrrayformula in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8Txi.jpg)I am trying to use this Query function within Arryaformula. I got stuck in this. Can anyone try to correct me as this code providing me some errors?
I will really appreciate your time.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY('RangeSelected'!1:1001,"SELECT * WHERE (LOWER(B) ='"&'Sheet1 column(A3)'&"'")",0))
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lK8IIy-nRPbGwvbguy0vvJrKOzyiGCFDVerK6I9oVXI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sheet is private

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY('RangeSelected'!1:1001,
 "where lower(B) = '"&LOWER(Sheet1!B5)&"'", 0))
```

Comment: Thank you, Thank you so much it worked. I was unnecessarily using that Aarayformula with the Query function. Sheet1 has a drop down input which is from 'rangeselected' Sheet this looks really prominent now. Thank you again. Shout out to you Brother.